# New tmux session which executes a script on startup

Tags: bash, scripts, startup, tmux

On startup, I want to have a new tmux session created which inside of that session changes directory and executes a bash script. How do I do this?

Cheers,

Tom

Comment: Are you aware of `cron`?

Comment: Yeah I am, but I do not know how to run commands on a new tmux session and schedule it for startup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) and [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login)

Answer (score 5):

Create the following script, but adjust it to your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a new session named "newsess" and run a command inside the session
tmux new-session -d -s newsess
tmux send-keys -t newsess "./path/to/myscript" Enter
# Attach to session named "newsess"
tmux attach -t newsess
```

- `newsess` is the name of the session
- `./path/to/myscript` is the full path of the script you want to run inside tmux.

Use any of the methods [described here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) to run the above script on startup.